# General approach for using Twisted in background to proxy TCP socket?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm looking for some general information on how I should approach a problem that I think Twisted is a great fit for. (I'm new to Twisted but not Python)

I have a home automation controller that can support a single TCP socket connection, sending and receiving binary data. I'd like to use XMPP as a bridge to the socket so a user can send commands and receive events.

I got a rudimentary socket connection working with Twisted that was able to send and receive commands from one of the examples in the O'Reilly book. I also have a fully working Python XMPP bot written with the SleekXMPP library that I'm happy with. I'm just not sure how to bring these together.

The basic scenario is:

1. User sends message to XMPP bot, which figures out what command to send to the socket
2. ASCII Socket command is converted to binary and sent to socket
3. Socket receives command and sends binary response
4. Binary response converted to ASCII
5. XMPP bot sends response back to user.
6. Network events (independent from user action) can also be received by network socket and should be sent to user

It's #6 that is presenting the challenge, otherwise I'd just open/close the socket on demand when in need to write something.

The part that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around with Twisted is the best approach to make these two event loops communicate. I've seen lots of info on using Queues, deferred, threads, select, etc. I have a feeling that Twisted can handle much of the complexity if I just learn to use the tool properly.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'll take the ball and run with it. As I mentioned, I'm happy with my XMPP bot and I'd like to use the existing code. I think my problem now comes down to creating the socket in the background, then sending and receiving data from that socket in the foreground.

By the way, I'm very happy to share back my code once it's working so someone else can benefit from the help I'm asking for.

-- Scott

Comment: I'm not sure what youre trying to do. What's the "background and foreground"? Are you thinking in terms of threads, because twisted does not use that concept. As I understand it, the messages go like `user -> bot -> proxy -> backend -> proxy -> bot -> user` and you want to write the proxy, translating between xmpp and some binary protocol?

Comment: I'd like to combine a Twisted event loop (reactor?) that manages a network socket with a SleekXMPP event loop running my XMPP bot. I need to communicate between these two - when network events happen, I need to pass them to a user via XMPP and when users send commands via XMPP, I need to be able to turn these into messages sent to my socket.

Some information pointed me towards using a Queue object as a way of communicating between threads, but if Twisted doesn't use threads, I'm not sure how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with a non-blocking IO engine is that its pretty much all-or-nothing. As soon as you introduce blocking code, you can quickly lose most of the benefits of the event-driven asynch approach. Wherever possible (as a rule of thumb), its best to have the entire app running off the same reactor.

As i see it, you have two options:

1. Twisted is not thread safe. That said, you can use mechanisms like [deferToThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/9.0.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#deferToThread) and [callFromThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.base.ReactorBase.html#callFromThread) to interact with other threads. This is by far the most confusing and needlessly complex approach for your application design. It's particularly painful if you're new to twisted.
2. Use twisted.words.protocols.jabber, and implement your XMPP stuff in a non-blocking manner using the twisted reactor. That way it will happily exist alongside all your other twisted code. and allow you to cleanly interact between protocols. It will result in less code, and a robust implementation that is easy to extend, maintain, and test.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. This is exactly the kind of info I needed. I'll look into Twisted words and then into tying the two together.